# Why does Print composer draw wrong coordinates?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer

QGIS Version: 2.14.3

EPSG: 32630 (WGS 84 UTM Zone 30N)

I´m trying to draw a grid with EPSG: 32630. Layers are in the same CRS. As you see, coordinates are completely off. It does not matter if I use decimals or degree. Doing the same in ArcGIS 10.4 works without problems, so I think the data is fine.

The real coordinates are around 43°N and 3°W. Is this just a bug in the current QGIS version? I did not use QGIS recently, so I do not know if this worked in previous versions like the current LTR (2.8).

[image]

Comment: what CRS did you select for the grid in composer? I would expect to see meters here

Comment: I selected EPSG: 32630 explicitly in the print composer. That's why I'm wondering also.

Comment: Just installed QGIS LTR 2.8.9 - same problem. Investigating the data again now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using a CRS in metres but trying the style it using a degrees based format. You'll either need to set the grid projection to a geographic one (ie WGS84), or use a different coordinate format.

Comment: You are right, the CRS I used is in metres. Changing it to WGS84 works with degree format. However I´m wondering why ArcGIS handles this issue (in the background?) without problems and QGIS can´t. Which coordinate format would you use in QGIS with a CRS in metres then?

Comment: You should use the "decimal" format